# Appending textbox to Wikipedia thumbnail picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Working on a small Javascript code that adds text from a clicked-href to the top right corner of the Wikipedia page. So for example, if I click the `Jamaican` link in [Sly and Robbie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sly_and_Robbie), a textbox would be appended to the page on the top right.

Note: to test this code, copy it and paste it to your console, then click some links.

```
// Detect click on href
$("a").click(function(event){
    // Capture the href from the selected link
    var link = this.href;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: link
    }).done(function(data){    
        // Find only the body text (not the titles.. or unnecessary text tips)
        var bodyText = $(data).find('#bodyContent #mw-content-text p').text();

        // Get the length of the text
        var length = bodyText.length;

        // Replace the text only if there is text in the clicked link
        if(length > 0) {
            replaceThumbnail(bodyText);
        } else {
            alert("No text found!");
        }

    });

    // Prevent the link from being executed
    return false;
});

/**
 * Append clicked body text to page thumbnail
 * @param  {string} text Body text
 */
function replaceThumbnail(text) {
    $(".infobox .vcard .plainlist").addClass($(".infobox").html(text));
}
```

My issue in particular right now is the `replaceThumbnail` function. I am trying to add the body text (of the clicked link) to the top right corner, on top of the Wikipedia page thumbnail. However, it seems with this code, I am simply replacing the thumbnail with this text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the method is that your selector

```
$(".infobox")
```

selects the whole box and replaces its contents with your text.

```
.html(text)
```

I've modified your replaceThumbnail function below:

```
function replaceThumbnail(text) {
    $(".infobox .vcard .plainlist").addClass($(".infobox tbody").prepend(text));
}
```

This will put your text at the very top of the info box.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you mind checking if my code follows JS best-practices?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with the addClass but I don't see why you would need it.

$(".infobox .vcard .plainlist").addClass(...);

Comment: I removed `addClass` and re-ran the code, but no errors or text would be appended. I used `addClass` because I want to use the styles within the textbox. Is this wrong?

Comment: If you want to make the content a part of the table and add styles I would do something like this instead. `$(".infobox tbody").prepend("<tr><td styles='whatever styles you want'>" + text + "</td></tr>");`

Comment: one minor issue. When I click on a new link, I want to remove the previously prepended text with the newly clicked text.

Comment: I modified the function so that your new element has an id so you can modify its inner text. `function replaceThumbnail(text) {
 if($('#infoText').length > 0) {
  $('#infoText').text(text);
 } else {
  $(".infobox tbody").prepend("<tr><td id='infoText' col-span='2'>" + text + "</td></tr>");
 }
}` So if it already exists just replace its text and if it doesn't exist add the element with the text.